# How to return a specific value based on if-condition in PostgresSql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
   time as "time",
   value as "value"
FROM metrics
WHERE 
   "time" BETWEEN '2021-07-08T05:14:55.652Z' AND '2021-07-08T11:14:55.652Z' 
   AND container = '1234' 
   AND tag = 'KEB1.DB_BC.01.STATUS.Actief_vermogen_tot_uit'
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That returns the following:

[image]

This number (value) can be negative (0 - -999999), 0 or positive (0 - 999999). However my frontend application can't work well with negative numbers so I want to transform the negative number to a positive number. Output should be something like this:

Any negative number = 1

0 =  2

Any positive number = 3

How can I achieve this in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
select time,
       (case when value < 0 then 1 when value = 0 then 2 else 3 end) as value
```

Or more concisely:

```
select time, ( sign(value) + 2 ) as value
```

Comment: Hi, case expression looks good. Where do I put this in my query?